# What does this kanji mean? How do I read it?

Tags: kanji, readings

[image: Kanji]

What does this kanji say? I don't know the radicals for it, therefore I haven't been able to look it up correctly.

Answer (score 6):

It says 「不潔{ふけつ}」, which means "unclean", "filthy", "dirty", etc.